# Cannot access state in handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner in React. I am building todo app. I'm trying to set input value to list using handleSubmit function. But strangely I am unable to access state in the `handleSubmit` function. I definitely know that I screwed at somewhere. Please let me know where I got screwed.

```
import React from 'react'

class Todo extends React.Component{
  state = {
    input : '',
    list : []
  }

  handleSubmit(){
   const listArray = this.state.input
     this.setState({
     list:listArray,
      input:''
     })
    console.log(this.state)
  }
  handleChange(e){

    this.setState({
      input:e
    });

  }
  render(){

    return(
      <React.Fragment>
      <input onChange = {(e) => this.handleChange(e.target.value)}
      value = {this.state.input}></input>
      <button onClick = {this.handleSubmit}>Click here</button>
      <ul>
      {this.state.list.map( (val) => <li>{val}</li>)}
      </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default Todo
```

Comment: Wrong "this" context; bind or use arrow function.

Comment: Arrow function does not change anything. Problem remains the same.

Comment: I find this unlikely--event handlers need to be bound to the class instance; binding in the constructor or using an instance property arrow function does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind functions inside constructor. Also define state inside constructor too.

Correct me if I'm wrong, you want to add new item to array after each submit. But in your code, you just assign your entered value to list. 
This will not work as intended. And you should use **li** tag with **key** attribute. 
I changed your code at [here](https://codepen.io/fkrsc/pen/eYYWyzO).

```
class Todo extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           input : '',
           list : []
       };
       this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
       this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to define state in constructor any more. But binding part is true, it should fix the problem.

Comment: I did as you suggested but nothing changed.

Comment: @GiriAakula Then something else is at play.

Comment: I cannot find what's wrong in my code. This is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-dan-yw8dj?fontsize=14

Comment: Thank you, I found the mistake. I'm assigning the value instead of modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Only the lifecycle methods will be called with `this` pointing to the component.

The event handlers will NOT point `this` to the component. So you will have to use arrow functions for event handlers or use bind in the constructor ( verbose )

Change

```
handleSubmit(){
```

to

```
handleSubmit = () => {
```

Same for the other handler